# append content of text file to other python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a "basic" python user and I'm trying to do following:

There is a file "input.txt" which is created each 5 minutes with different content. Now I'm just trying,each time the file is generated, to copy (or better to say to append) the whole content to an file "output.txt":

```
with open("input.txt",'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    with open("output.txt", "a") as f1:
        f1.writelines("lines\n")
        f1.write("--This-is-just-a-line-to-differ-the-content-blocks")
```

Now, I'm able to copy the content, but the file "output.txt" is each time overwritten. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it worked with:

```
with open("file.txt",'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("output.txt", "a") as f1:
    f1.writelines(lines)
    f1.write("--This-is-just-a-line-to-differ-the-content-blocks")
f.close()
f1.close()
```

@Reinier Hernández Ávila: Thx for the tipp with f.close(). But in this case the overwriting argument "a" worked and not the "w".

Answer (score 1):

That happened because you are writing the output file, not the input file

```
with open("file.txt",'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
with open("output.txt", "w") as f1:
    f1.writelines(lines)
    f1.write("--This-is-just-a-line-to-differ-the-content-blocks")
f.close()
f1.close()
```

Comment: There is no need to call `close` on the file objects, because using them as a context manager ensures they are closed at the end of the block